# Gradle sync error in Android Studio 2.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

This error occurs on every gradle sync.

Comment: It would be best if you included some information on a few of the things you have tried in your efforts to solve this problem. From my perspective, it seems like you have a dependency in gradle for junit, but perhaps the link is invalid.

Comment: The image you have attached has the root cause it self. Then troubleshoot.

Comment: Check the `link` you have given for *Junit* and also you make sure you are connected to *Internet*.

Comment: ok Then Can we remove the dependency ?

Comment: yes remove junit dependency

Comment: Do you have working internet connection?

Comment: Yes 40Mbps internet connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below mentioned path:

Right click on your application/project -> open module settings-> Go to "Dependencies" tab -> you'll find "junit:junit:4.12" -> select it and right click and choose remove option -> ok

Now again try to build your application.